# Silverlight and the back button

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to override the behavior of the back button in the browser when using a Silverlight app?

Essentially what I want to do is use the browser's back button to close dialogs in my application. The dialog covers the whole screen and the user would be inclined to think they are on a separate web page.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the following links:

- [Prevent Browser Back Button for Silverlight with Confirm Dialog](http://mrpanot.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/prevent-browser-back-button-for-silverlight-with-confirm-dialog/).
- [Silverlight - Prevent users from losing changes by using the browser back button](http://blog.gfader.com/2010/08/silverlight-prevent-users-from-losing.html)
- [Managing Silverlight 3 navigation
  behavior](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/04/06/silverlight-3-navigation-behavior-customization.aspx)